# importing module elements in another with no qualified name

Tags: python, python-import

My problem is quite easy but I can not find a good answer because the search engines are ambiguous on the term "module".
What I want do to is roughly this :

*Module : a.py*

```
x = 2
```

*Module : b.py*

```
import a
```

Now, I want to be able to access `x` from `b` without using qualified name (i.e. without typing `a.x`, just with `x`). In my situation I cannot use :

```
from a import x
```

because I don't know which elements `a` will contains. I can not use

```
from a import *
```

neither. Is there any simple way to merge or join the modules (I mean the Object Modules) ?

Comment: You don't want much, do you?

Comment: Why can't you use `from a import *`?

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* a good idea, but you can use:

```
globals().update(vars(a))
```

to add *all* names defined in the `a` module to your local namespace. This is almost the same as `from a import *`. To emulate `from a import *` exactly, without using `from a import *` itself, you'd have to use:

```
globals().update(p for p in vars(a).items() if p[0] in getattr(a, '__all__', dir(a)))
```

You normally just would use `x = a.x` or `from a import x`.

If you are using `zipimport` you don't have to do any of this. Just add the path to the archive to your `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/archive.zip')
from test import x
```

Comment: In fact i don't want to import all names from **a**, just some of them (depending on their type). I'll try your solution, but i thought there was a "safer" alternative to updating globals()

Comment: @ibi0tux: It is not at all clear why using `x = a.x` and such is not something you can do. Dynamically adding names to your namespace requires manipulating `globals()` or using `exec`, and I cannot recommend the latter when `globals()` will do.

Comment: Actually the module is imported with zipimport and i have something like :
`a = zipimport . zipimporter ( "archive.zip" )`

`mod_a = a . load_module ( "test" ) # considering archive.zip contains a module test`

`print mod_a . value # considering value is defined in module test`

Is there any way to make the import directly in global ?

Comment: @ibi0tux: See, why didn't you post than in your question to start with? You can just add the zip module to your `sys.path` and import normally.

Comment: Does this mean i don't need to use zipimport ?

Comment: You don't *have* to use `zipimport`.

Comment: hm .. this does resolve the problem. I tried something but it still need to do an `from X import *` to get names in global

Comment: @ibi0tux: But *why* can't you use `from X import namea, nameb, namec`? What is preventing you from doing that?

Comment: In my situation i'm importing a zip containing python, but i don't know what contains the zip before the import, and i want to import classes only

Comment: But why do you have to add them to the global namespace? Can't you add them to a `dict()` or a `list()` after testing for classes?

Comment: I prefer adding them to the global namespace to use the names without any prefix.

Comment: Is it possible to use `__import__` instead of `import` or is it a bad practice ?

Comment: `__import__` is a hook method; it's like calling `__getattribute__` directly on an object instead of using `getattr()`, or working your way through `__dict__` and `__class__` and it's `__bases__` instead of using `dir()`. Use `importlib` or `import` instead.